# How i catch the response from a server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When i create a form like this:

```
<form method='POST' action='gate.py'>
    <input type='file' />
</form>
```

1) How i cant catch the response from the server, on a script?

2) I can send in a async way a file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you heard [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) ?

Comment: @Reigel: $.ajax() alone is not suitable for file uploads.

Comment: If i have an auto generated xml document to upload with the file, theres any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to post your form to a hidden iframe:

```
<iframe id="hidden-frame" name="hidden-frame" src="" style="width:0; height:0; display: none;;"></iframe>
<form method="POST" action="gate.py" target="hidden-frame">
    <input type="file" />
</form>
```

Then from your "gate.py" script return some JavaScript code according to the result of the upload:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    alert('Upload Successful');
</script>
```

You could also interact with the parent to update a `<div>` with the response.

On the other hand, you could also consider using a third-party plugin like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/what-is-it/).

Comment: Thanks your answer, but it's painful to me because i want to pass a xml document and the file but the xml document it's auto-generated by the page.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look:

Ajax File Upload:
http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html

JQuery Form Plugin:
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started